# View not updating - angular, firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This function fires once at page load, but then never again. I've tried $watch, $apply, and firebase's ref.on('value', ... but no dice. The model changes for the value of scope.job.getApplicants(), but scope.applicants_ is not refreshing when this happens.

```
function go() {

    var p = [];

    // scope.job.getApplicants() returns a $firebaseArray of user IDs
    scope.job.getApplicants().$loaded().then(function(list) {

      list.forEach(function(app) {

        // User_(app.$id) returns a $firebaseObject
        var user = User_(app.$id);     


        p.push(user);   

      })

    });

    return p;
  }       


  scope.applicants_ = go();
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to give more code? In plnkr maybe?

Comment: @geckob got it working, see below

Answer (score 2):

This is how I resolved the problem:

```
ref.on('value', function(apps) {
    var applicantIDs = Object.keys(apps.val());       
    scope.applicants_ = applicantIDs.map(function(app) {
      return User_(app);
    });
});
```